# long integer value objective-c

Tags: objective-c, long-integer

I have long integer value ( ex: 2705758126 ) in NSString.

When i try to show it: NSLog(@"%i", [myValue integerValue]); it return: 2147483647.

How to show, compare and etc. this long integer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try with

```
NSLog(@"%lld", [myValue longlongValue]);
```

Comment: I made an edit to fix the case in the method. I had to add a link because edits of less than 6 characters are not allowed... (That is very annoying, and has bitten me on more than one occasion.)

Answer (score 4):

[The documentation recommends](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW5) using @"%ld" and @"%lu" for NSInteger and NSUInteger, respectively.  Since you're using the integerValue method (as opposed to intValue or longLongValue or whatever), that will be returning an NSInteger.

Comment: @IlDan No, he has an NSString that he's converting to an NSInteger which means it might be an int (on 32-bit machines) or it might be a long it (on 64-bit machines).

Comment: Oh well, I tend to listen to what people say. I'm reading "I have long integer value".

Comment: @IlDan yeah I missed the NSString bit the first time reading it, too. =)

Comment: Seems to me the poster has a string that contains a number which will overflow a 32 bit value. Therefore NSInteger won't be good enough on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: @Stig 2^32 = 4,294,967,296, which is 1,589,209,170 larger than the number given in the question.  How would it not fit in a 32-bit int?

Comment: @Dave DeLong the method `integerValue` returns a signed number. the signed 32 bit int's max is (2^31)-1, not 2^32

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html). NSString has the following method:

```
- (long long)longLongValue
```

Which should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

from this example here, you can see the the conversions both ways:

```
NSString *str=@"5678901234567890";

long long verylong;  
NSRange range;  
range.length = 15;  
range.location = 0;  

[[NSScanner scannerWithString:[str substringWithRange:range]] 
       scanLongLong:&verylong];

NSLog(@"long long value %lld",verylong);
```