# How to overcome the 2,147,483,647 issue NSNumberFormatter

Tags: iphone, ios5, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

```
-(NSString *)convertCurrency:(NSString *)textFieldString{
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
    [numberFormatter setGroupingSize:3];
    [numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
    [numberFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
    [numberFormatter setMaximumIntegerDigits:20];
    number= [NSNumber numberWithInt:[textFieldString intValue]];
    NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",[numberFormatter stringForObjectValue:number]];
    return numberString;
}
```

When I send the textfield string value is send 10000000000 only return the $2,147,483,647 but I want only $10,000,000,000. how to solve this issue.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor bigger data type means longlongvalue i also try that method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `long long`. That's assuming $9,223,372,036,854,775,807 is enough.

```
NSNumber* number = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[textFieldString longLongValue]];
NSString* numberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

BTW you could have just used

```
[numberFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@"$"];
```

instead of `-stringWithFormat:` to add the dollar sign.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#

You are getting your value as an int, and the max. value an int can hold is 2147483647.
You have to use another type such as long.

Check this Question: [long integer value objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147569/long-integer-value-objective-c)

Comment: I am using using Longlongvalue but this time return as $1,410,065,408